# Is there an explanation for Talbot's abilities?

Tags: uncharted-3

In Uncharted 3, Talbot (Katherine Marlowe's main henchman) appears to have supernatural powers. He suffers no ill-effects after being shot by Cutter, and can jump incredibly high. Is there ever any explanation for these powers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the hallucination sequence in the "Atlantis of the Sands" chapter, Talbot is seen throwing a smoke bomb at Drake. This could mean that Talbot is simply using special effects to give the illusion that he's a ghost, or that he's invincible.

---

- Shot by Cutter

  - Bulletproof vest
- Disappearing around the corner

  - Smoke bomb
- Forcing Cutter and Drake to do his bidding

  - Sodium pentathol dart, "truth serum"

Answer (score 1):

I can't recall where he jumped very high, but in the scene where he gets shot by cutter, we don't see any blood, we can assume he was wearing some kind of body armor

Answer (score 1):

I've heard from several people that he's an illusionist, able to trick people into seeing things. That being said, he's a pretty cool character, but I totally know what you mean. I think when he got shot it was a bullet proof vest.

Comment: but how does talbot dissapear in the scene when he shoots cutter witth that black ops thingy, he just goes in the corner and dissapers